# Adding Google Comments to Website?

Tags: google-plus

So Google has their own comment system, similar to Facebook Comments or Disqus. The problem I am having is the complete lack of documentation on this feature. For instance, I know I can use this code to add a comment box:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js"></script>
<div class="g-comments"
    data-href="[URL]"
    data-width="642"
    data-first_party_property="BLOGGER"
    data-view_type="FILTERED_POSTMOD">
</div>
```

But how do I customize this further? What do first_party_property and "view_type" mean? What are the other options for that data? How can I make the width responsive? How do I define moderators? Etc...

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Can't you check out the plusone javascript and figure out a bit more? Maybe rewrite a piece of javascript after the plusone javascript. I think that's your best bet. And as far as I know they only implement it where and when they want. Not as usable as disqus from FB at this moment.

Comment: Have you looked at the javascript? Its one of the most unreadable things I have ever seen.

Comment: I haven't looked at the javascript. But if it's formatted like that it's intentional so you can't integrate and use it in your website or application. Even if you figured out the right tags to use and code to match I'm quite sure google runs some sort of verification wherever it's used or installed. So your empty shell of google comments probably wouldn't have functioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no documentation because it's a private widget not designed for third-party use. Use it at your own risk as the tag format may change or the API may disappear altogether. The only way to know what the properties mean is to reverse engineer it or Google for info from others reverse engineering it.